# Downloading Qiime to CentOS6.4. Having problems with python version

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, qiime

I'm trying to download Qiime to CentOS 6.4. and having troubles with the version of python. I have not much experience dealing with Linux system.

I've already downloaded python 2.6.6 in /usr/bin/python and I think this is the default version of python when I checked.

I tried to download python 2.7.6 since program Qiime can only be downloaded with python 2.7 to 3.3.
I downloaded python 2.7.6 to /usr/local/bin/python2.7

I wanted to use python 2.7.6, so I tried alias python=/usr/local/bi/python2.7

However, when I tried to download Qiime with "pip install qiime" commend, it generates this error: 
The required version of distribute (>=0.6.28) is not available,
and can't be installed while this script is running. Please
install a more recent version first, using
'easy_install -U distribute'.

(Currently using distribute 0.6.10 (/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages))

---

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 2 in /tmp/pip-build-onqyfu/matplotlib

Is it because the default version of python is still 2.6? What should I do to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to Linux, too, but was experiencing a similar problem recently.

Perhaps your `PATH` and/or `PYTHONPATH` is still pointing to the older version of python. You can check this by using the commands:

```
echo $PATH
echo $PYTHONPATH
```

If it is indeed pointing to the wrong place, you can reset these to wherever you want them to go...

I think for you this would look like the following, but double check that this is where your new version of python is installed.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib:$PYTHONPATH
```